# RxJava Android - Load-cache-display data on proper threads

Tags: android, multithreading, caching, rx-java

I'm exploring the RxJava and its applicability to Android, and I'm trying to implement a simple load-cache-display use case, as depicted on the following ASCII graph:

```
                    ---------------
      --- failure --|  Load data  |-- success ---
      |             ---------------             |
      V                                         V
-------------------                       -------------
|  Get from cache |                       |   Filter  |
-------------------                       -------------
      |                                         |
      |                                         V
      |            ----------------       -------------
      ------------>|    Display   |<------|    Cache  |
                   ----------------       -------------
```

Here's the code that I initially came up with:

```
subscription = AndroidObservable.bindFragment(this, restClient.getItems())
                .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, List<Item>>() {
                    @Override public List<Item> call(Throwable throwable) {
                        return itemsDao.getCachedItems();
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<ItemContainer, Observable<Item>>() {
                    @Override public Observable<Item> call(ItemContainer itemContainer) {
                        return Observable.from(itemContainer.getItems());
                    }
                })
                .filter(new Func1<Item, Boolean>() {
                    @Override public Boolean call(Item item) {
                        return item.getName().startsWith("B");
                    }
                })
                .toList()
                .map(new Func1<List<Item>, List<Item>>() {
                    @Override public List<Item> call(List<Item> items) {
                        itemsDao.cacheItems(items);
                        return items;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<List<Item>>() {
                    @Override public void call(List<Item> items) {
                        displayData(items);
                    }
                });
```

As expected, networking and caching are performed on a background thread, and displaying the data happens on UI thread. The problem is that data returned by `onErrorReturn()` goes through the same filtering and caching cycle, which is redundant. However, if I change the code to this:

```
subscription = AndroidObservable.bindFragment(this, restClient.getItems())
                    .flatMap(new Func1<ItemContainer, Observable<Item>>() {
                        @Override public Observable<Item> call(ItemContainer itemContainer) {
                            return Observable.from(itemContainer.getItems());
                        }
                    })
                    .filter(new Func1<Item, Boolean>() {
                        @Override public Boolean call(Item item) {
                            return item.getName().startsWith("B");
                        }
                    })
                    .toList()
                    .map(new Func1<List<Item>, List<Item>>() {
                        @Override public List<Item> call(List<Item> items) {
                            itemsDao.cacheItems(items);
                            return items;
                        }
                    })
                    .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, List<Item>>() {
                        @Override public List<Item> call(Throwable throwable) {
                            return itemsDao.getCachedItems();
                        }
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Action1<List<Item>>() {
                        @Override public void call(List<Item> items) {
                            displayData(items);
                        }
                    });
```

`displayData()` is never called. What would be the right way to compose these observables to implement the scheme that I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by replacing `onErrorReturn()` call with `onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just(itemsDao.getCachedItems()))`